# Не могу выложить приложение в Google Play

Tags: android, kivy, google-play, apk

Хотел выложить своё приложение в Google Play, а потом столкнулся с трудностями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как не оптимизирован? Что не оптимизирован? И КАК ВООБЩЕ ЕГО ОПТИМИЗИРОВАТЬ?

Comment: Как вы генерируете файл для загрузки?

Comment: Можете помочь это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Google Play` отдается предпочтение оптимизированным файлам. Этот инструмент называется [Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle). Документации говорится так:

> App Bundle это новый формат который вмещает в себя весь код программы,
>   но оставляет подписание пакета установки и формирование APK Google.

То есть вы должны сформировать app-bundle и выгрузить его в google play console, а все остальное сделает за вас `Google`. С учетом того что вы работаете не в `Android Studio` то Google советует использовать так называемый [bundle-tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build). [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720980/python-kivy-apk-how-to-use-android-bundle-for-fix-googleplay-error) есть подобный вопрос. В [документации](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html) kivy советуют для подписания приложений использовать `Buildozer`. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) документация от Google по поводу ручного подписания приложений.

Comment: А ещё можете, пожалуйста, помочь, какой командой в bundle-tool из *.apk получить подписанный *.apk?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool - вот тут есть все команды

Comment: Но там ведь по суте, импортируется из aab в apks.
`bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks`

Comment: я думаю можно формат изменить

Comment: К сожалению, не работает

Comment: Что именно вы делали и что не работает. Можно так выложить и apk но он должен быть подписан ключем

Comment: Я прописал эту строчку:
```java -jar bundletool-all-0.13.3.jar bundletool build-apks --bundle=E:\calculator.apk --output=E:\calculator.aab```


(По любому, что-то не так сдалал)